# Thread safe class is being terminated

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread safe class like the following

```
public class ThreadedClass extends Thread {
  public ThreadedClass() {
    // Some code
    listener();
  }

  public void run() {
    // Some code
  }

  public void listener() {
    // Code that's checking for messages from a server
    String test = // lots of stuff here
  }
}
```

This is being executed in a test class like the following

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadedClass t1 = new t1();
    t1.start();
  }
}
```

The problem is, I want to have a callback from the thread that's running, so when listener() get's a message I can notify Test(), check the message, and perform some action.  To do this I wrote an interface and added the following to listener()

```
this.callback.messageRecieved(message);
```

This executes, but terminates the thread.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: try using t1.join() after t1.start();

Comment: Could you show the complete code? It is not clear how do you add a listener.

Comment: Hang on, if you're checking messages in the `listener()` method, which is called from the constructor of `ThreadedClass`, that's still running in the caller thread.

Comment: @MortezaAdi There's no reason why main thread should hang around and wait for the new thread to terminate if it isn't going to do anything _after_ the new thread terminates.  The new thread is not a daemon thread, so the JVM (and the new thread) will keep on running even after main() returns.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Test {

  public void notify(){//notify};  

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Main Thread here 1
    ThreadedClass t1 = ThreadedClass.getInstance();
    //Main Thread 3 
    //Main Thread starts a Thread : Thread-1
    t1.start();
    //*****Main Thread 4 (Parallel Execution here. Thread-1 is listening when Main Thread is here) 

  }
}

public class ThreadedClass extends Thread {

  private ThreadedClass instance = null;      

  private ThreadedClass() {

  }

  public static synchronized ThreadedClass getInstance(){
     //Main Thread 2 
     if(instance == null){
        return instance = new ThreadedClass();
     } 
     return this.instance;
  }    

  public void run() {
       //Thread-1  1
        listener();
       //Thread-1  2
  }

  public void listener() {
    // Code that's checking for messages from a server
    String text = // lots of stuff here

  }
}
```

As I understand your code,you are writing socket programming.You call listener method in constructor
and listener has input stream with blocks ThreadedClass initialization.

I write the listener method call in run method so when you start the thread listener method will be called. Also I pass the Test refrence in ThreadedClass so you can call any method in Test

Also your classes are always thread safe. You are not using static method or singleton class.
If you initialize for each class you don't have any problem with multi threading issues.

Comment: Please add an explanation of your solution together with the code.

Comment: @user3087839 I'm working on an MQTT project and want to execute the class once as a thread and just let it listen while I continue on with other code execution.

Comment: I didn't write in eclipse. I just wrote it here so there can be small bugs.